# Why won't the Authorize attribute work with my roles?

Tags: asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I cannot figure out why ASP.NET Identity does not work with my roles. I created a custom UserStore and a custom RoleStore. In my UserStore I implemented the `IUserRoleStore` interface, and I expected at least one of those methods to be called when ASP.NET determines if the user should be authorized to call a given endpoint, but none of the methods are getting hit.

I registered the services like this:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, ProReceptionRole>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ProReceptionRole>, RoleStore>();
```

I also tried registering the services using this variant (with and without the `AddRoles` part - and with different ordering of the extension methods):

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, ProReceptionRole>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
    .AddRoles<ProReceptionRole>();
```

When I add the `[Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")]` attribute to my controller class, then I get 403 Forbidden, even for users that have the given role.

I read through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but I can't spot my problem. The only part that I am unsure about is that it says `If you are using Roles, update the RoleManager to use your RoleStore class.` - and I am assuming that this is done when I register my RoleStore, but maybe I have to do something extra?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Søren Pedersen, 403 in your requirement means the User login with unsupported role. Pls check if the user owns the correct role.

Comment: Thanks, @Rena - the user does own the correct role, and that is why I was very confused. However, it seems that nothing links these together by default - and I have now created a middleware that adds role claims to the authenticated user, and this works! (so actually in this project I have gotten rid of the `AddIdentity` stuff since the project needs to work with some legacy tables from the old SimpleMemebership system)

Comment: Hi @Søren Pedersen, did you add the authentication and authorization middleware? And the order should be :`app.UseRouting();`, `app.UseAuthentication();`, `app.UseAuthorization();`.